# I cannot replace a JavaScript file

Tags: drupal, drupal-templates

I want to remove a JavaScript file from my Drupal website, and add a custom one. This is the code I'm using in my template.php file, but it doesn't work (the old js file is still loaded). (I've cleared the cache)

function zen_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

```
/*update js file*/
$scripts = drupal_add_js();
unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js']);
$scripts['module']['sites/all/themes/zen/zen/myjs/lightbox.js'] = array('preprocess' => 1, 'cache' => 1);
$variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
```

Comment: any good tip ? I've inspected the scripts array, the old path is correctly replaced, but still the old js (and not the new one) is loaded.

Comment: have you seen this: http://www.mediacurrent.com/blogs/remove-or-replace-jscss-page ?

Comment: thanks for link. The point is that the path is actually replaced in the Array, but the old file is still loaded by Drupal. They told me I just need to add these lines to template.php file without using modules at all

Comment: ups.. or maybe I am wrong and the function should be run from template.php file (zen_registry_alter) ?

Comment: anyway I've tried both solutions (I've also added the function myNewModule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) to myNewModule.module file but none of the functions described in the article are never invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your code, and it actually works, if you place it in `hook_preprocess_page()`. Your problem is probably that you use the wrong proprocess function, so that it doesn't effect the $scripts variable you use in your page template, or that is it overridden somewhere later in the process.

**Edit**

- You should not edit the Zen theme directly, but sub theme it instead.
- Have you tried adding the JavaScript file with `drupal_add_js()`?
- Have you inspected `$variables['scripts']` after changing it to see if it was as expected?

Comment: well, I'm using it at the end of zen_preprocess_page in my template.php file. Is that correct ? Indeed it partially works because the $scripts array is correctly updated but the old js file is still loaded instead of the new one.

Comment: so yeah.. I'm updating the scripts variable, but my template page is still using the old one... should I refresh theme registry.. after that lines ?

Comment: I saw you updated the question. This is what I'm saying.. the  $variables['scripts'] is perfectly updated. But the variable $scripts in my theme page is not.

Comment: @Patrick: Then you either don't pass the $variables var by reff, or the scripts variable you use in the page template is overridden somewhere else. Try naming it something else and use that in your page template. This should help you debug the problem.

Comment: ok, i solved.. thanks. It was very stupid of me. The var $variables was supposed to be $vars instead.